# Allocating UITextViews in specific positions

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a circle at the center of the screen, and I am allocating around this fixed circle (a UIImageView) a series of UIlabels. the number of the labels is given by the number of elements in an NSMutableArray, and the position  of the labels depends on the number of labels. I can't give a fixed x and y coordinate to the labels, because the number of labels will vary.

I tried using this code:

```
- (void)loadContent{

NSString *filename6 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Setting"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *groupPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename6]];

NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:groupPath];

NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]];

int arrayCount = array.count;
int yCoordinate = (2*M_PI) / arrayCount;
int xCoordinate = ;

for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++){

    CGRect textframe = CGRectMake( the xcoordinate, the ycoordinate, 328, 30);
    NSString *nameOfGroup = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    UITextView* theGroupTextLabel;
    theGroupTextLabel = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textframe];
    [theGroupTextLabel setText: nameOfGroup];
    [theGroupTextLabel setTextColor: [UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:theGroupTextLabel];

    //theGroupTextLabel.enabled = NO;
    theGroupTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.5f;
    theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    int z;
    z = z + 1;
    theGroupTextLabel.tag = z;

 }
}
```

but i am stuck with finding the right equation for the:

```
int yCoordinate = (2*M_PI) / arrayCount;
int xCoordinate = ;
```

...coordinates. Any ideas? Is this the right method I am using?

Comment: How are these labels being positioned? In a grid? or are they in a circle around the image(like the numbers on the face of a clock)? I noticed you have an M_PI in there so I'm guessing it's like a clock?

Comment: the are displayed in a circle round the image, yes like a clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a math question than a code question, but I'll take a stab.

Assuming you want the first item at the top, and then placing items clockwise around the main image, you are going to be altering one variable as you go through the for loop: the angle.

You then calculate the x and y coordinates in each iteration by converting your angle and radius(which is likely constant) to cartesian coordinates, and adding the result to the coordinates of the center of the image. This needs to be done within the for loop, not at the beginning as you have it in your code.

The amount you will add to the angle on each iteration of the loop is `2*M_PI / arrayCount`.

This is roughly what I'm thinking:

```
- (void)loadContent{

NSString *filename6 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Setting"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *groupPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename6]];

NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:groupPath];

NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]];

int arrayCount = array.count;

CGFloat radius = 300;// <--- INSERT RADIUS HERE
CGFloat angle = 0;// <--- The starting angle
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(300,300); // <--- INSERT CENTER OF ARRANGEMENT

for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++){
    int yCoordinate = radius * cos(angle) + center.y;
    int xCoordinate = radius * sin(angle) + center.x;

    CGRect textframe = CGRectMake( the xcoordinate, the ycoordinate, 328, 30);
    NSString *nameOfGroup = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    UITextView* theGroupTextLabel;
    theGroupTextLabel = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textframe];
    [theGroupTextLabel setText: nameOfGroup];
    [theGroupTextLabel setTextColor: [UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:theGroupTextLabel];

    //theGroupTextLabel.enabled = NO;
    theGroupTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3.5f;
    theGroupTextLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    int z;
    z = z + 1;
    theGroupTextLabel.tag = z;

    // INCREMENT ANGLE
    angle += 2 * M_PI / array.count;
 }
}
```

Comment: This code is great, but can you please briefly explain me what is the center of arrangement and the "insert radius here"?

Comment: The center point is where you want the items to radiate from, generally it would be the coordinates of the center of your large circle image. The radius is the distance from the center of the circle to it's edge, this will probably be one half the length of your large circle image. I didn't see a reference to that image in your code or I would have just used that, so you'll have to fill in those numbers yourself.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with a circle, your X and Y coordinates are `(cos angle, sin angle)` so inorder to figure out your x and y coordinates you should probably do something like the following

```
float angle = (2*M_PI) / arrayCount;
int xCoordinate = (cos(angle * i) * circleRadius) + circleCenterX;
int yCoordinate = (sin(angle * i) * circleRadius) + circleCenterY;
```

This will give you the point on the circle where the label should appear.

**N.B.** you need to multiply the `angle` by `i` in order to move the next label to the right position. You might also have to add 1 to the array count when calculating angle to prevent the last one overlapping the first label.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)